# Where Visual Studio install ProjectTemplates and ItemTemplates

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2008 and i installed and removed StrataFrame Framework.

This framework installed in my system some ProjectTemplates and ItemTemplates, when i removed this continue visible in VS.

Where VS save ProjectTemplates and ItemTemplates files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run "devenv.exe /installvstemplates" to update VS template cache.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749979/visual-studio-2008-how-to-install-an-item-template) (*Visual Studio 2008: How to install an item template*)